# Facing issue on library flavor selection in android

Tags: android-productflavors

I have created a library called mylibrary with two product flavors like virtual and nonvirtual like below

```
flavorDimensions "dev"

productFlavors {
    virtual {
        dimension "dev"
    }
    nonvirtual {
        dimension "dev"
    }
}
```

and I have implemented the library in my project LibraryTesting like below

```
implementation project(path: ':mylibrary')
```

Now, when I trying to select different build variant its showing errors like "Module 'LibraryTesting.mylibrary' has variant 'nonvirtualDebug' selected, but the module 'LibraryTesting.app' depends on variant 'virtualDebug'"

please find the below image for more information

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare library flavor to use in build.gradle from LibraryTesting project:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        missingDimensionStrategy 'dev', 'virtual'
    }
```